# Use dictionary to filter javascript data object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter

Say I have a filter:

```
filter = [ {key: "pl", value: 3}, {key: "sh", value: 2} ]
```

I want to filter the following javascript object with the above filter conditions:

```
var data = [
{title: "The Uncertainty of the Poet ",
pl: 3,
si: 2,
va: 3,
te: 0,
co: 0,
or: 4,
sh: 2,
po: 0,
li: 0,
ar: 5
},
{
title: "Direction",
pl: 4,
si: 3,
va: 1,
te: 3,
co: 0,
or: 3,
sh: 2,
po: 0,
li: 0,
ar: 5
}
...
]
```

I tried the following with no luck:

```
var result = data.filter(function(d){
            for (item in filter) {
                return d.key==d.value;
            }
```

Comment: what is your expected result? Do you want to return the entire object if the filter is matched?

Comment: I want to return the object with only the entries that match the filter conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another potential option to check if the object meets all the criteria:

```
data.filter(function(obj) {
    return filter.reduce(function(a, f) {
        return a && (obj[f.key] === f.value);
    }, true);
});
```

That will work without having to check for hasOwnProperty because of the use of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). If you wanted to check for if any of the filter conditions are true, you would change it to

```
data.filter(function(obj) {
    return filter.reduce(function(a, f) {
        return a || (obj[f.key] === f.value);
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks sbrass. The first worked how I was hoping it to. Since my filter conditions update dynamically, it returns the data object with entries that meet all of the conditions selected and stored in filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way as well:

```
var filters = [{key: "pl", value: 3}, {key: "sh", value: 2}]

var data = [
    {
        title: "The Uncertainty of the Poet ",
        pl: 2,
        si: 2,
        va: 3,
        te: 0,
        co: 0,
        or: 4,
        sh: 3,
        po: 0,
        li: 0,
        ar: 5
    },
    {
        title: "Direction",
        pl: 3,
        si: 3,
        va: 1,
        te: 3,
        co: 0,
        or: 3,
        sh: 2,
        po: 0,
        li: 0,
        ar: 5
    }
]

var result = data.filter((item) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < filters.length; ++i) {
    let filter = filters[i];

    if(item[filter.key] && item[filter.key] === filter.value) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going deep enough with your `for in`. It is looping over the array and not working with each object in the array

Can use [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to make sure every object in filter array has match in the data object

```js
// filter main data
var result = data.filter(function(dataObj){
   // check if all proprties within filter array are a match
   return filter.every(function(filterObj){
      //compare value of property found in filterObject with value 
      return dataObj[filterObj.key] === filterObj.value
   })
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
var filter = [ {key: "pl", value: 2}, {key: "sh", value: 3} ]

var data = [{
    title: "The Uncertainty of the Poet ",
    pl: 2,
    si: 2,
    va: 3,
    te: 0,
    co: 0,
    or: 4,
    sh: 3,
    po: 0,
    li: 0,
    ar: 5
  },
  {
    title: "Direction",
    pl: 4,
    si: 3,
    va: 1,
    te: 3,
    co: 0,
    or: 3,
    sh: 2,
    po: 0,
    li: 0,
    ar: 5
  }
 
]
</script>
```

Comment: I think we might need to check if the property exists just in case. So something like dataObj[filterObj.key] && dataObj[filterObj.key] === filterObj.value

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai if it doesn't exist would simply `=== undefined` and would not match or throw error

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai Simple example `var foo={a:1}; console.log(foo.bar)//undefined`

Comment: Yep I tested it already. I removed my answer since it doesn't add anything useful.

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai would only be problematic if there were nested properties involved

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to match one or the other values, this will work:

```
match = [ {key: "pl", value: 3}, {key: "sh", value: 2} ]

var result = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.pl === match[0]['value'] || d.sh === match[1]['value']
})
```

I've changed the name of the array to `match` to avoid confusion.

Comment: What if filter array has 3 (or more ) elements and the keys in each of it's objects  are unknown?